# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am receiving this error while executing balance-transfer example on docker toolbox.

```js
{"success":false,"message":"failed Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed 
with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]"}
```

Comment: Check if your port is exposed or not. See in your docker file for the ca service, the port must be passed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Docker Toolbox does not expose ports on localhost.  It uses a different network address.  You will need to replace "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" with the IP address provided when Docker Toolbox starts.  You can usually find it in the Docker Quickstart terminal